# using gridlayout to create a calendar

Tags: android

I am creating a calendar-like layout using GridLayout.

One way i can think of is defining a parent GridLayout and thirty TextViews with 30 unique IDs in the XML layout file.

But, instead of simple TextViews, if i want a compound control for each day(like a couple of buttons and TextViews), i could create an custom item layout for it and define 30 of these items inside the GridLayout. But that would mean i have 30 different click listeners as well!

Is there a more sensible approach to create a calendar?

Comment: create an Adapter for the GridLayout...

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez you mean for the `GridView` right? I don't think `GridLayout` has an adapter interface.

Comment: ups you're right. Sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

**Its best to use varoius codes that are available on Internet because calender Implementation is very difficult you have to check no. weeks ,leap year and so so use this link to add calender**

[https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView]

Comment: not true, with Java you have classes responsible for date calculation so all you need to do is to create a view to display them, and it is not a complex task. surely you can use 3rd party but trying to do it yourself will be a great lesson.

Comment: if you want to create custom gridView.setOnitemClickListener() this will do your work .you dont need clicks on individual items

Comment: thanks nice one! I'll be stealing a lot of this code to create my own implementation.